# Scrape auto-captions from youtube

Tags: javascript, ruby, api, youtube, web-scraping

Does anyone know the best way to scrape auto captions from youtube? I want to use the captions in another web application. I already can get captions that have been uploaded by the user by using: http://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v={VIDEO-ID}&lang=en

However, that request does not work for videos that only have auto generated captions. I was thinking one solution may be to automate clicking the transcript button on a youtube video and then grabbing the divs that contain the captions, but I am unsure exactly how to implement that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what an auto-caption is? And what is your aim, maybe show an example.

Comment: @kwoxer Basically, auto captions are captions that youtube generates automatically using there algorithm. Auto captions are the default captions if an uploader does not provide custom captions. Here's a video that uses auto captions:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BHQIasisqY All I want to do as of now is to get the captions from a video (for both auto and user uploaded captions) and use them in my own application.

Comment: Ahh you mean *subtitles*. Because a caption is something else my friend. Alright. Now I understand.